# Geom_text issue with label on a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

Based off the iris data set I'm trying to create a bar chart with the average Sepal Length for each Species as the label for each bar.

Reproducible example:

```
#load data
iris1 <- as.data.frame(iris)

#packages
library(ggplot2) #visualizations

#create bar chart with average Sepal Length for each Species as the label
ggplot(data = iris1, aes(x = iris1$Species, y = iris1$Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y ="mean",  fill = "light blue") +
  labs(title = "Sepal Length by Species", x = "Species", y = "Sepal Length") +
  geom_text(label = iris1$Sepal.Length)
```

Output:
[image]

```
ggplot(data = iris1, aes(x = iris1$Species, y = iris1$Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y ="mean",  fill = "light blue") +
  labs(title = "Sepal Length by Species", x = "Species", y = "Sepal Length") +
  geom_text(label = mean(iris1$Sepal.Length))
```

Output:
[image]

I'd expect the graph to show 1 label of the average Sepal Length for each bar (setosa, versicolor, and virginica).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
ggplot(iris1, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", fill = "light blue") +
  stat_summary(aes(label=..y..), fun.y=mean, geom="text", size=8)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works, thank you. What do the periods mean in label=..y..?